# How to add callouts in xlsxwriter using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, xlsxwriter

Hi is there any way to adding a callout box in an excel sheet.
something like https://www.officetooltips.com/word_2016/tips/adding_callouts_to_objects.html

I am making exporting an excel from a dataframe using xlsxwriter.

Any help :)

Comment: Callouts aren’t supported in XlsxWriter. The only Excel shape that is supported is the TextBox.

Comment: @jmcnamara thank you for update, is there any other option available in python for using callouts ?

Answer (score 1):

**To use XlsxWriter with Pandas you specify it as the Excel writer engine:**

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a Pandas dataframe from the data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Comment: i wanted to use/add  call outs. i am alredy ding that, my question was how can i add callouts